# PHP image editing: image quality keeps getting worse after each edit

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd

Hi everytime I have a button that allows users to rotate an image. However everytime the user rotates the image (which is a JPEG), the quality gets worse. How do I prevent this from happening?

php file

```
   //create src image and grab destination image from folder then...

   imagecopyresampled($new_image, $src_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
   $rotated_image = imagerotate($new_image, $angle, 0);
    imagejpeg($rotated_image, $new_image_file_path, 100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPEG is a lossy format.  If you're not going to store the original, quality will degrade with each re-compression.

It is possible to [losslessly rotate a JPEG](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/), but neither GD nor ImageMagick support lossless rotation.  You will need to find a library that does, or implement an algorithm manually.